# resource routes without member id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I develop a Rails application and I added simple route:

```
Name::Application.routes.draw do
  resource :categories
end
```

The problem is that there is no member id in the generated URLs:

```
$ rake routes
categories      POST   /categories(.:format)      categories#create
new_categories  GET    /categories/new(.:format)  categories#new
edit_categories GET    /categories/edit(.:format) categories#edit
                GET    /categories(.:format)      categories#show
                PUT    /categories(.:format)      categories#update
                DELETE /categories(.:format)      categories#destroy
```

I use Rails 3.2.3. I don't use ActiveRecord in the application (but I don't know if it is relevant). I have a model `Category` and `CategoriesController`.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You forgot to add `s` in the end:

```
resources :categories
```

`resources` and `resource` are different things: [resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) and [resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).

Comment: Same, lost 15 minutes on this, damn it.